# Expose TSL/SSL server on azure app service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a custom server on an APP Service on Azure that only accepts requests on HTTPS instead HTTP.

My idea is deploying using the APP Service for avoid deploying on myself any SSL certificate.

I have found this on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux) of the APP Service:

> App Service terminates TLS/SSL at the front ends. That means that TLS/SSL requests never get to your app. You don't need to, and shouldn't implement any support for TLS/SSL into your app.

> The front ends are located inside Azure data centers. If you use TLS/SSL with your app, your traffic across the Internet will always be safely encrypted.

So when I try to access via HTTPS on the 443 port the requests are being sent to port 80 and by HTTP. I tried to expose the port 443 directy using the config WEBSITES_PORT but result is that as that port doesn't accept HTTP request, the APP Service is not starting and keeps rebooting some time.

> 2022-09-14T16:05:22.335Z ERROR - Container xxxx_3_4a82d922 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 443, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

My question is, is there any possibility to resend those HTTPS requests to the 443 as HTTPS on the APP Service in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this at all? TLS termination is a normal thing in most architectures. If you want to enforce HTTPs for incoming connections, there is a setting in the app service. If you want more control on how requests are handled between load balancer and server you might want to use AKS, VMs, Container Instances in combination with App Gateway or maybe Frontdoor

Comment: Hi @JulianHüppauff, I want to try this approach as it's too simple creating app services instead the alternatives you mention. AKS, VMs can require maintenance and container instances as far I've seen it's kind of complicated for having SSL connections (trustables) in a quick and easy way. Which setting do you say about en force https for incoming connections? Thanks.

Comment: In the App Service under TLS/SSL Settings you can find the protocol settings - here you can set HTTPs only and even provide own certificates.

Answer (score 1):

So your App Service essentially runs on a VM in isolated regions of Azure Data Centers often referred to as Stamps or Scale Units.

Unless you are on an ASE, your App Services live on these stamps which are multi tenant environments sharing a few incoming load balancers and the later is where TLS/SSL is terminated and is the entry point for your app. From the load balancer, the traffic is routed to a proxy (for linux apps) such as Nginx on a VM, over http and forwarded from there to the port exposed by your app service app(docker containers in linux). The defaults are 80 or 8080 but you could change this using the setting WEBSITES_PORT (note the use case here).

So you wouldn't really need end to end TLS given the above architecture. You could turn on the HTTPS only flag in your App Service->Configuration->General settings blade and this would redirect all http requests at the front end to https. This still would not result in end to end TLS.

TLS is often terminated outside the applications in the infrastructure (API gateway or Traffic Managers for instances) and this is by design and offer many benefits (less overhead, certificate management etc).